# How to query / transform the data into the desired format

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I wonder if anyone can help me to transform the below data (from a database) into
List.:

| Lorryid | productid | qtytype | Qty | iscomment | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4090 | 3 | 2 | f |  |
| 1 | 4153 | 3 | 1 | f |  |
| 1 | 4153 | 3 | 1 | f |  |
| 1 | 4153 | 3 | 1 | f |  |
| 1 | 4153 | 3 | 1 | f |  |
| 1 | 4153 | 3 | 1 | f |  |
| 1 | 31068 | 3 | 2 | f |  |
| 1 | 31069 | 3 | 2 | f |  |
| 1 | 31173 | 3 | 2 | f |  |
| 2 | 17 | 0 | 1.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 150 | 3 | 6.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 216 | 3 | 6.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 278 | 2 | 1.020 | f |  |
| 2 | 398 | 2 | 1.125 | f |  |
| 2 | 398 | 2 | 1.090 | f |  |
| 2 | 398 | 2 | 0 | t | MUST BE RIPE |
| 2 | 431 | 2 | 3.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 436 | 3 | 1.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 446 | 0 | 1 | f |  |
| 2 | 446 | 2 | 3.045 | f |  |
| 2 | 451 | 3 | 2.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 457 | 3 | 1.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 458 | 3 | 4.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 478 | 3 | 1.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 510 | 2 | 1.140 | f |  |
| 2 | 518 | 3 | 3.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 518 | 3 | 4.000 | f |  |
| 2 | 550 | 2 | 1.170 | f |  |
| 2 | 550 | 3 | 1.000 | f |  |

Into the below object.

```
public class View
{
  public List<LorryLoading> Report
}

public class LorryLoading
{
  public int LorryId
  public List<Product> Product
}

public class Product
{
  public int ProductId
  public decimal Qty0 sum(Quantity) WHERE QtyType = 0
  public decimal Qty2 sum(Quantity) WHERE QtyType = 2
  public decimal Qty3 sum(Quantity) WHERE QtyType = 3
  public List<string> Comments
}
```

Is it possible to do with a single projection? Having problems on assigning lists.

Also, any links where I can learn such transformations? The examples
I've found so far are rather simple or poorly explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq's `Aggregate` to do a custom aggregation. This is slightly more complex as you have a double aggregation going on here.

Note that this will probably only work with Linq-to-Objects.

```cs
var report = data
    .GroupBy(row => row.Lorryid)
    .Select(l => new LorryLoading {
        LorryId = l.Key,
        Product = l
            .GroupBy(row => row.productid)
            .Select(p => p.Aggregate(
                new Product {ProductId = p.Key},  // this is the starting object
                (prod, row) => {                  // this aggregates it up
                    if(comment != null)
                        prod.Comments.Add(row.comment);
                    if(QtyType == 0)
                        prod.Qty0 += row.Quantity;
                    else if(QtyType == 2)
                        prod.Qty2 += row.Quantity;
                    else if(QtyType == 3)
                        prod.Qty3 += row.Quantity;
                })
            .ToList()
     }).ToList();

var view = new View {Report = report};
```

Answer (score 1):

What You're asking is a transformation, so there is no simple projection. You can probably do it with a super complicated statement which will make Your colleague change job when they have to maintain :) my suggestion is to not try to impress campus but focus on clean code:

```
var lorryLoadingReport = new List<ReportData>();
//Presume you already have data into a transport object and know how to read that, as it wasn't your question

var view = new View
{
    Report = new List<LorryLoading>()
};
var listOf = new List<Product>();
        
//Lets not over complicate our mind, just keep it simple, let's get the products and the lorries
var productsList = lorryLoadingReport.Select(x => x.ProductId).ToList();
var lorriesList = lorryLoadingReport.Select(x => x.LorryId).ToList();
foreach (var lorry in lorriesList)
{
    //We'll need an entry even if the list will be empty
    var lorryLoading = new LorryLoading
    {
        LorryId = lorry,
        Product = new List<Product>()
    };

    //Get the respective subset
    var lorryLoadingReportPerLorry = lorryLoadingReport.Where(l => l.LorryId == lorry);
    if (lorryLoadingReportPerLorry.Any())
    {
        foreach (var productId in productsList)
        {
            //And add a product with all 4 sums iteratively
            var p = new Product
            {
                ProductId = productId,
                Comments = new List<string>()
            };
            var commentsList = lorryLoadingReport.Where(x => x.ProductId == productId && x.IsComment == "t").Select(s => s.Comment).ToList();
            if(commentsList.Any())
                p.Comments.AddRange(commentsList);
            p.Qty0 = lorryLoadingReport.Where(x => x.Qty == 0).Sum(y => y.Qty);
            p.Qty2 = lorryLoadingReport.Where(x => x.Qty == 2).Sum(y => y.Qty);
            p.Qty3 = lorryLoadingReport.Where(x => x.Qty == 3).Sum(y => y.Qty);

            lorryLoading.Product.Add(p);
        }
    }    
    view.Report.Add(lorryLoading);
}
```

Comment: obviously example can be cleaned-up-before-code-review a lot, and should, but to outline a solution to somebody clearly with no example given of being even close, I think it serves to illustrate a simplified approach to the problem, and it does help with the transformation

Comment: Thanks for that. Was doing similar thing to achieve the result but done the group by on select from database. And I concur that maintainable > fancy code.